# MAUI project ListView Item not display correct when Navigate from other Tab

Tags: .net, maui

I have a project written with .net MAUI. In this project , I have one TabBar with three bottom navigations. Like this:

1. **AppShell.xaml** :

```
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Route="index" Title="Books" Icon="index.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Views:IndexPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="datamanage" Title="Datas" Icon="datamanage.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Views:DataManagePage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="setting" Title="Setting" Icon="setting.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Views:SettingPage}" />
    </TabBar>
```

2. In IndexPage, It displays datas with ListView, the Listview Binding datas from Sqlite Databases.
   The items in Listview is called Category, when click the Category Items. This IndexPage navigate to CategoryPage.
3. The **CategoryPage.xaml** is like this:

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="AddCategory" Text="Edit" Clicked="AddItem_Clicked"/>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="DeleteCategory" Text="Delete" Clicked="DeleteItem_Clicked" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image x:Name="icon" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding IconID}" Aspect="Center"  />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding Account , StringFormat='{0} >>'}" />

                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="Blue" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="LightGrey" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Remark}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView >

    </StackLayout>
```

And the **CategoryPage.xaml.cs** is like this:

```
public partial class CategoryPage : ContentPage,IQueryAttributable
{
    MindBookDatabase mDatabase;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public List<Item> ItemsList { get; set; }
    int CategoryID = 0; 
    public CategoryPage(MindBookDatabase db)
    {       
        InitializeComponent();
        
        this.mDatabase = db;

        this.BindingContext = this;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }   

    public async void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    { 
        var category = query["category"] as Category;
        CategoryID = category.ID;

        List<Item> items = await mDatabase.getItemsByCategoryAsync(category.ID);

        Items.Clear();
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            if(item.CategoryID == category.ID)
            {
                Items.Add(item);
            }            
        }
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }

    private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Item item = e.Item as Item;
        var param = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "item", item } };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"Item", param);
    }

    private async void AddItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
        ViewCell viewCell = menuItem.Parent as ViewCell;
        var item = viewCell.BindingContext as Item;

        var param = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "op", "modify" }, { "ItemID", item.ID } };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"AddNewItem", param);

        //DisplayAlert("title", item.Name, "OK");
    }

    private async void DeleteItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
        ViewCell viewCell = menuItem.Parent as ViewCell;
        var item = viewCell.BindingContext as Item;
        string tmpItemName = item.Name;

        await mDatabase.DeleteItemAsync(item);
        await Toast.Make($"delete {tmpItemName} succeed.").Show();

        List<Item> items = await mDatabase.getItemsByCategoryAsync(CategoryID);
        Items.Clear();
        foreach (var tmp in items)
        {
            if (tmp.CategoryID == CategoryID)
            {
                Items.Add(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. The **two Problems** is :

**First Problem:**
When I enter the App it display IndexPage, After I click one Category item, It Navigate to Category Page. Then I clicked the bottom Tab (from Books tab to Datas tab navigate from each other 20 times or more) , The problem appears as following : The Line in the Listview is very big, I dont know why this problem happened.

The snapshot is as following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixFEd.png)

**Second Problem:**
When the first problem happened,  I also cliked one Listview item too enter the Item detailed Page. And Navigate from Item detailed Page to Category Page Agein , then One Problem happened as the following snapshot: The listview is empty, But But But I can click the empty Item, It can Navigate to the Item detailed Page. I also dont know why and How to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8cy3.png)

I want to solve the problem:  If navigate from other tab , Make Listview display items conrrectly .

Comment: 1) If you don't click on Books or Datas tabs, just do Category Page -> click one item -> back to Category, are the item contents visible? 2) similar to (1), but add one extra click on a different tab, then back to Category?

Comment: 1) Yes. If I DON'T click on Books or Datas Tabs, then everything is ok.  2) If I add one extra click , everything is ok.

Comment: One thing I want to mention here: I noticed that some information from the output window: [TabLayout] MODE_SCROLLABLE + GRAVITY_FILL is not supported, GRAVITY_START will be used instead ;  This information always there for long time.

Comment: Make a new issue at `github maui issues`. Include a link to a public github repo, containing just enough code to run and see the problem.

Comment: Did this happen when you added a new item for the ListView?

Comment: No. If I add a new item, everything is ok.

Comment: First, you can try to use the `OnAppearing()` method to get the data for the ListView. Second, the Line in the Listview is very big, it looks like an issue and you can report it on the github.